# Microsoft Azure notebook

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, microsoft-account, azure-notebooks

How do I upload a CSV file for my data science project which is of 100MB in Microsoft azure notebook? Whenever  I try to upload it it says that the file needs to be less than 10MB.

Comment: maybe split it in to 10 separate files if you must use that service

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Notebooks preview will be retired on January 15th, 2021, and all user data will be destroyed.
Ref : Microsoft offical website